# Office 365 single tenant multiple domain multiple sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, office

I have two tenancies lets call them `ten1.com` and `ten2.com`. Each one has their own SharePoint `ten1.sharepoint.com` and `ten2.sharepoint.com`. `ten1` is being migrated into `ten2`.

The users and domain name are being kept as they were in `ten1`. The company has merged but is still separate. `ten1` migrated users will still use `ten1` as their domain for email/skype etc. It's my understanding that if I migrate SharePoint from `ten1` it would then become `ten2.sharepoint.com/ten1`. I need to keep the SharePoint separate so in `ten2` I would have `ten1.sharepoint.com` and also `ten2.sharepoint.com`.

Is this possible and how could I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

One sentence in advance: If you ask google about this topic, you get a lot of information about a feature named "Public Site". This feature is no longer available, so all that information is invalid for today's deployments.

If you enable SharePoint on your O365 tenant, you will be assigned a URL `tenant.sharepoint.com`. This cannot be change or extended right now. So think well about your tenant name!

If you want to migrate your existing SiteCollection from `ten1` you need to create a SiteCollection as you already mentioned (`ten2.sharepoint.com/tensite1`). I would recommend you to use an ISV-Tool to perform migration (ShareGate, Metalogix). "Save as Template" can also work, but with lots of limitations (e.g. doesn't work with publishing-features enabled).